# Import And Export Sqflite File using firebase and flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Is there is a way to import and export Sqflite file to firebase storage. I already have created sqflite file and firebase storage but doest not know how to import /export

Comment: Are you need to add backup feature or something else?

Comment: yes exactly i want this feature

Comment: You can start [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/). In few words - you need to load a database file to Firebase Storage when you creating backup and download backup file from Firebase when you need to restore it. You can replace exists database file by file from Firebase.